# PHP's $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA in ASP

Tags: php, html, actionscript-3, vbscript

I'm updating a classic asp page with a flash app and I need to reproduce the PHP's $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA function under vbscript (OR C# .NET since it's on IIS7 also). This is what I have so far but does not work. The browser just tells me that it can not display the image because of errors or corruption. Thanx in advance.

AS3 Code

```
vid_out = new Video();
vid_out.x = 0;
vid_out.y = 0;
vid_out.width = cam.width;
vid_out.height = cam.height;
vid_out.attachCamera(cam);
addChild(vid_out);

var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(640, 480);
bitmapData.draw(vid_out);
var encoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder();
var byteArray:ByteArray = encoder.encode(bitmapData);
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("/capture.asp?i=blah.jpg");
jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
jpgURLRequest.data = byteArray;
navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest, "_blank");
```

non-working vbscript code

```
Function RSBinaryToString(xBinary)
  Dim Binary
  If vartype(xBinary)=8 Then Binary = MultiByteToBinary(xBinary) Else Binary = xBinary

  Dim RS, LBinary
  Const adLongVarChar = 201
  Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  LBinary = LenB(Binary)

  If LBinary>0 Then
    RS.Fields.Append "mBinary", adLongVarChar, LBinary
    RS.Open
    RS.AddNew
    RS("mBinary").AppendChunk Binary
    RS.Update
    RSBinaryToString = RS("mBinary")
  Else
    RSBinaryToString = ""
  End If
End Function

photoname = trim(request.querystring("i"))

Dim ByteCount, BinRead
ByteCount = Request.TotalBytes

If ByteCount > 0 Then
BinRead = Request.BinaryRead(ByteCount)
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" & photoname
Response.BinaryWrite(RSBinaryToString(BinRead))
Response.End()
End If
```

'working vbscript code

I'm just using the actual folder path located on the server. You can user servermappath also.

```
photoname = trim(request.querystring("i"))
folder = "C:\some_folder\"

tofolder = folder & photoname

Dim BinaryData, ByteCount 
ByteCount = Request.TotalBytes 
BinaryData = Request.BinaryRead(ByteCount)

Set objADO = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objADO.Type = 1
objADO.Open
objADO.Write BinaryData
objADO.SaveToFile tofolder, 2
Set objADO = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Request Object reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524948%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Specifically, you will be interested in [`Request.TotalBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524728%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property to get request body size and [`Request.BinaryRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525710%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method to read the request body.

*Quote from MSDN:*
**VBScript**

```
<% 
Dim vntPostedData, lngCount 
lngCount = Request.TotalBytes 
vntPostedData = Request.BinaryRead(lngCount) 
%>
```

Comment: thanks for the code, it pointed me in the correct direction. I added the working code to my post